# Best way to define module for both node and client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a small module that I want to be available both on the Browser and Node.js environment.

So far I've come up with the following

```
(exports && window = exports)

(function(global){

    // make it available to either exports OR window depending on the environment
    global.Awesome = function() {

    }

})(window)
```

is that sufficient or is there any better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider just creating your module as you normally would for Node and then using Browserify to use it on the client as well.  Basically you just write a script file and use 'require' to pull in your module and make use of your module functions right there.  Then you use Browserify to create a single file that you just include in the src attribute of a script tag in your html file.

http://browserify.org